# Why is there no finite subcover for open sets?

Tags: real-analysis

If $A$ is an open and bounded set, then why is $A$ itself not a finite subcover of $A$?

Comment: Subcover of what?

Comment: A *is* a finite cover.  Why did you think  it wasn't.  Of course to be *sub*cover there needs to be a cover for it to be a subcover of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compactness is not about finding an open cover in general. Every topological space has an open cover (namely, the whole space itself). Compactness is a game that is being played. If **I** give you an open cover, can **you** find a finite subcover? For instance, let's consider $(0,1)$. If I give you $\{(0,\frac{1}{2}), (\frac{1}{3},1)\}$ as a cover of this space, you can clearly give me a finite subcover.

On the other hand, if I give you $\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \{(\frac{1}{n},1)\}$ as a cover of this space, there is no way you can find a finite subcover. Therefore, this space is not compact (under the usual topology given to this space).

Answer (score 6):

Given an open set $A$, the collection $\{A\}$ **is** an open cover of $A$. However, the criterion for compactness, which is what I assume you are concerned with, requires that **every** open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover. Therefore, it is not enough to claim that just because one open cover, $\{A\}$ of $A$ has a finite subcover, then **every** open cover of $A$ does.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, looks like I missed that important detail that every open cover of $A$ must have a finite subcover. However, can you please also explain how is the existence of an open subcover for every cover of $A$ related to $A$ being closed and bounded?

Comment: I think this might be of use: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are assuming that if someone gives you a cover $\{U_{\alpha}\}$ for a bounded open set $A$ then it is the case that one of the $U_{\alpha} = A$ which is not true. Consider this example,

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't work. If the lengths *are* fixed, then you will obtain a finite subcover.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: yeah ur right, forget the counterexample, think I still answered the confusing part of the OP's assumption.